# What is the total volume of wood used for the model?

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume

[image]

A person makes a model of a house in construction class. The block of wood for the base measures 6 inches by 4 inches, and is 4 inches tall. He used a triangular prism for the roof, whose rectangular face hangs over the base by half an inch on all sides and is 4 1/3 inches in height.Calculate the total volume of wood used for the model. Is this question as simple as finding both volumes of both shapes and adding them together?

Volume of triangular prism= 1/2 * l * w * h
Length = 7 inches
height = 4.333333333 inches
Width = 5 inches
V = 75.83333333

Rectangular prism volume = l x w x h
Length = 6 inches
Width = 4 inches
Height = 4 inches
v = 96

So, would the total volume of wood used for the model be 171.83 inches?

Comment: I think it would be better if you used fractions (such as 4-1/3) instead of the decimals.

Comment: It is that simple. The calculations look OK too.